# Hide `cd something` when shopt autocd is enabled

Tags: command-line, bash

When `shopt -s autocd` and I navigate to any folder (for example the `~/Projects` folder), I get `cd ~/Projects` in the terminal output and then move to the `~/Projects`. How can I hide the output of what `shopt` just did? (the `cd ~/Projects` thing): [image: the screenshot]

Comment: [From this five-year-old post](http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/how-to-silence-shopt-s-autocd-verbose-tp6038p6040.html) there is no way to do so (note that Chet Ramey maintains bash).

Comment: Zsh doesn't print such a message, if that helps.

Comment: @muru well, that's bad. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @muru thanks for the zsh suggestion. I've switched on it :)

Comment: dang that's too bad i was looking for a way to do just that D:
is there a way to do this 5 years later? XD

Comment: aha! [i found a way](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cn1i20/suppressing_output_from_autocd_on_bash/) sadly it make have unintended consequences

Answer (score 1):

> This output (and a lot of other
>   automatically-generated Bash output) is sent to the same file
>   descriptor that set -x uses, so you could use:
>
> `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>/dev/null`
>
> to redirect it into `/dev/null`.
>
> This appears to leak a file descriptor into all executed processes,
>   however, which is probably undesirable. (I'm slightly surprised by
>   this... I would have thought the BASH_XTRACEFD file descriptor would
>   be marked close-on-exec.)

Is what i found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cn1i20/suppressing_output_from_autocd_on_bash/) but i am unsure of the consequences of this redirection nor do i know how to reverse it

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to use the `BASH_XTRACEFD` redirect trick, but preserving the behavior of `set -x`, this is how I did it:

```bash
shopt -s autocd

# silence_autocd
# - Hack to stop autocd from printing the directory after autocd'ing.
# - Unfortunately there is no clean way to do this except messing with
#   BASH_XTRACEFD, a poorly understood file descriptor that we are better not
#   to mess with, yet here we are.
# - Warning: This might break things, so try disabling it if something looks
#   off.
silence_autocd() {
  exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>/dev/null
}

silence_autocd

# unsilence_autocd 
# - Needed to undo the above temporarily.
# - Unfortunately, BASH_XTRACEFD is used for other things besides autocd.
# - In those cases, I need to undo and redo the redirection.
# - Currently "set -x" is the only notable user of BASH_XTRACEFD that I've
#   found so far, but there could be others in the future.
# - For the time being, I pray to the Bash Gods to provide a native way to
#   disable autocd printing soon.
unsilence_autocd() {
  exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>/dev/stdout
}

# custom set
function set () {
  # if calling "set -x", undo the silencing of autocd
  if [[ "$#" == 1 && "$1" == "-x" ]]; then
    command set -x;
    unsilence_autocd;
  elif [[ "$#" == 1 && "$1" == "+x" ]]; then
    silence_autocd;
    command set +x;
  else  
    command set "$@";
  fi;
}
```