# what are the consequences of redirecting BASH_XTRACEFD to /dev/null?

Tags: bash

I looking for way to [Hide `cd something` when shopt autocd is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701084/hide-cd-something-when-shopt-autocd-is-enabled/1212122#1212122) and ended up finding [i can redirect BASHTRACEFD to /dev/null](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cn1i20/suppressing_output_from_autocd_on_bash/) but i'm unsure what would happen if i did that. What would break and what output i would miss.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following consequence for redirecting BASH_XTRACEFD to /dev/null so far:

- `echo "test"` gets redirected to /dev/null
- `docker ps` get redirected to /dev/null